# Cinemachine keeps locking mouse pointer while using UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I am not that good at programming and just used the third person starter assets to start my game. However, when I used Photon Fusion, there is a menu with the server connection buttons. You cant click on them though because the mouse pointer is locked. How do I fix this?

Comment: I can't quite provide adequate help without seeing your setup, but this article, https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-lock-hide-the-cursor-in-unity/, addresses the general way the mouse cursor is locked in Unity (or specifically `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None`). However, I'm not sure that's sufficient to solve your problem.